# Query Returning SUM of Quantity or 0 if no Quantity for a Product at a given date

Tags: sql

I have the following 4 tables:

```
----------
tblDates:

DateID

30/04/2012
01/05/2012
02/05/2012
03/05/2012

----------
tblGroups:

GroupID
Home
Table

----------
tblProducts:

ProductID   GroupID
Chair       Home
Fork        Table
Knife       Table
Sofa        Home

----------
tblInventory:

DateID      ProductID   Quantity

01/05/2012  Chair       2
01/05/2012  Sofa        1
01/05/2012  Fork        10
01/05/2012  Knife       10
02/05/2012  Sofa        1
02/05/2012  Chair       3
03/05/2012  Sofa        2
03/05/2012  Chair       3
```

I am trying to write a query that returns all Dates in **tblDates**, all **GroupIDs** in **tblGroups** and the total Quantity of items in each **GroupID**.

I manage to do this but only `get Sum(Quantity)` for **GroupID** and **DateID** that are not null. I would like to get 0 instead. For exemple for the data above, I would like to get a line `"02/05/2012 Table 0"` as there is no data for any product in "Table" group on `01/05/12`.

The SQL query I have so far is:

```
SELECT tblDates.DateID, 
       tblProducts.GroupID, 
       Sum(tblInventory.Quantity) AS SumOfQuantity
FROM (tblGroup 
     INNER JOIN tblProducts ON tblGroup.GroupID = tblProducts.GroupID) 
     INNER JOIN (tblDates INNER JOIN tblInventory ON tblDates.DateID = tblInventory.DateID) ON tblProducts.ProductID = tblInventory.ProductID
GROUP BY tblDates.DateID, tblProducts.GroupID;
```

I reckon I should basically have the same Query on a table different from **tblInventory** that would list all **Products** instead of listed products with 0 instead of no line but I am hesitant to do so as given the number of **Dates** and **Products** in my database, the query might be too slow.

There is probably a better way to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To get all possible `Groups` and `Dates` combinations, you'll have to `CROSS JOIN` those tables. Then you can `LEFT JOIN` to the other 2 tables:

```
SELECT
    g.GroupID
  , d.DateID
  , COALESCE(SUM(i.Quantity), 0)  AS Quantity
FROM 
        tblDates  AS d
    CROSS JOIN
        tblGroups AS g
    LEFT JOIN
            tblProducts  AS p
        JOIN
            tblInventory AS i
          ON i.ProductID = p.ProductID 
      ON  p.GroupID = g.GroupID
      AND i.DateID = d.DateID 
GROUP BY
    g.GroupID
  , d.DateID
```

Answer (score 0):

use the isnull() function. change your query to:

```
    SELECT tblDates.DateID, tblProducts.GroupID,
            **ISNULL( Sum(tblInventory.Quantity),0)** AS SumOfQuantity
    FROM (tblGroup INNER JOIN tblProducts ON tblGroup.GroupID = tblProducts.GroupID) 
    INNER JOIN (tblDates INNER JOIN tblInventory ON tblDates.DateID = tblInventory.DateID)
            ON tblProducts.ProductID =  tblInventory.ProductID
    GROUP BY tblDates.DateID, tblProducts.GroupID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which database you're using but what I'm familiar with is Oracle.

Obviously, if you inner join all tbales, you will not get the rows containing nulls. If you use an outer join to the inventory table you also have a problem because the groupid column is not listed in tblinventory and you can only outer join to one table.

I'd say you have two choices. Use a function or have a duplicate of the groupid column in the inventory table.

So, a nicer but slower solution:

```
create or replace
function totalquantity( d date, g varchar2 ) return number as
  result number;
begin
  select nvl(sum(quantity), 0 )
  into result
  from tblinventory i, tblproducts p
  where i.productid = p.productid
  and i.dateid = d
  and p.groupid = g;
  return result;
end;

select dateid, groupid, totalquantity( dateid, groupid )
from tbldates, tblgroups
```

Or, if you include the groupid column in the inventory table. (You can still quarantee integrity using constraints)

```
select d.dateid, i.groupid, nvl(i.quantity, 0) 
from tbldates d, tblinventory i 
where i.dateid(+) = d.dateid 
group by d.dateid, g.groupid
```

Hope this helps,
  Gísli

Comment: What do you mean with *"you can only outer join to one table"*? You can have multiple outer joins in a query.